# Apache adding php.ini overwrites all global php.ini settings

Tags: php, apache

I just want to add something very simple to my php.ini settings

```
post_max_size = 2.5M
upload_max_filesize = 2.5M
```

But if I add a php.ini file to my documentroot, a lot of stuff changes. I'm pretty sure this is because it's no longer using the global php.ini which has some stuff in it. Can I not simply *append* some settings instead of *overwriting* everything?

Edit: My server is in CGI mode which doesn't allow me to use .htaccess to set php.ini settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override ini settings:

- right from your php script with `ini_set()` function.
- in .htaccess file using format `php_value setting_name setting_value`

Comment: Are these the only options? .htaccess doesn't work in my case and I'd rather not have settings in the scripts.

Comment: Dont you have access to .htaccess? Or it just doesnt work?

Comment: Check the edit to my question; it's a security thing I think.

Comment: Seems like it is not possible. Either you have a full copy of php.ini or use one of the above two options.